# Can i make android studio downloads manually?

Tags: android, android-studio

I installed Android Studio but i need install in the application some components such as the android sdk. My internet connection is very poor and every time the connection has problem the download of these components fail and reset. If i click on more details it shows the urls to download. Can i download these urls individually? And what should i do next to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sdkmanager` to install packages from the command line, for example

```
sdkmanager "platforms;android-33"
```

use

```
sdkmanager --list
```

to list the packages available.

Check https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/sdkmanager#options for the command line options.

Answer (score 1):

Install the SDK
Within Android Studio, you can install the Android 12 SDK as follows:

Click Tools > SDK Manager.
In the SDK Platforms tab, select Android 12.
In the SDK Tools tab, select Android SDK Build-Tools 31.
Click OK to install the SDK.